# Random number groups

Tags: java, android-studio

I am making app where shows me on display random set of numbers. And here is my question becouse my code looks like that:

```
tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                final java.util.Random rand = java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom.current();
                new java.util.Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new java.util.TimerTask() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        tv1.setText(rand.nextInt(6) + "-" + rand.nextInt(6) + "-" + rand.nextInt(6));
                    }

                }, 0, 3000);


            }
        });

    }
}
```

Is it possible that the application instead of numbers from 6 to 0 would take ready sets of numbers that I create?

Comment: for example. (1-2-3, 1-3-5, 1-5-6). 
something like that
 this code sometimes shows me undesirable combinations

Comment: No no . I mean sometimes app shows me (3-5-4 or 5-6-6)  and I don't want these types of combinations to display on the screen

Comment: These sequences show in random sequences. Removing them would make the sequences less random.

Answer (score 0):

Implement the method given below inside your **activity class** and you can use it to achieve your requirements:

```
// To get the numbers from 0 to 6 use upperBound as 7.
private static String getResult(int lowerBound, int upperBound){
        final ThreadLocalRandom rand = ThreadLocalRandom.current();
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int number;

        for(int counter = 0; counter < 3;counter++){
            number = rand.nextInt(lowerBound, upperBound);
            while(list.contains(number)) {
                number = rand.nextInt(lowerBound, upperBound);
            }
            list.add(number);
        }
        Collections.sort(list); //Sorts the list
        return list.get(0) + "-" + list.get(1) + "-" + list.get(2);
    }
```

In your **TextView** `tv1` inside `run()` method; simply call this method, something like:

```
tv1.setText(getResult(0, 7)); // Remember in the sequence; 0 is inclusive and 7 is exclusive.
```

You can see the sample run [**here.**](https://onlinegdb.com/HkVAxUHoI)

Comment: it is possible to create a folder, enter your jumeric sequences there and the application would take what to randomize from there?

Comment: Not quite. I wanna make in android studio kind of folder with numbers that i wanna show on display. For example I am making folder with numbers (1, 4, 534, 94,) and app will draw lots only this numbers

Comment: I don't understand ;/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to draw random numbers from a `List`, you can use `rand.nextInt(list.size())` to get a random index to draw a number from, as the upper bound argument for `nextInt` is exclusive.

```
final java.util.List<Integer> numbers = java.util.Arrays.asList(1, 4, 534, 94);
btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final java.util.Random rand = java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom.current();
                new java.util.Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new java.util.TimerTask() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        tv1.setText(numbers.get(rand.nextInt(numbers.size())) + "-" + numbers.get(rand.nextInt(numbers.size())) + "-" + numbers.get(rand.nextInt(numbers.size()));
                    }
                }, 0, 3000);
            }
        });
    }
}
```